# How to declare global variables using TestNG/Selenium/Java?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am totally new in automated testing.
For practice purposes, I want to create tests for the contact form in Selenium with TestNG. [This is the page](http://automationpractice.com/index.php) I am using for practice. I created several test cases but I am not sure how to declare variables that I will be calling later on (in the same class). The code is below, I would like to declare 'Email', 'ErrorField' and 'SendButton' - all suggestions are much appreciated since I tried several ways and I am getting errors.

```
public class FormValidation {
  protected static WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest()
  public void beforeTest() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
  }

  @Test(priority = 0)
  public void blankFormTest() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=contact");

    WebElement SendButton = driver.findElement(By.id("submitMessage"));
    SendButton.click();
    WebElement ErrorField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center_column\"]/div/ol/li"));
    {
      Assert.assertEquals(ErrorField.getText(), "Invalid email address.");

    }
  }

  @Test(priority = 1)
  public void correctEmailonly() {
    WebElement Email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    Email.sendKeys("kasiatrzaska@o2.pl");
    WebElement SendButton = driver.findElement(By.id("submitMessage"));
    SendButton.click();
    WebElement ErrorField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center_column\"]/div/ol/li"));
    {
      Assert.assertEquals(ErrorField.getText(), "The message cannot be blank.");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Actually you created one class variable already: `protected static WebDriver driver;` - you can do the same with any other variables, e.g. `private static String submitMessage = "submitMessage";` at the start, and then use the variable anywhere in the class.

Comment: Please google page object model.

Answer (score 0):

*You can do it with **By declaration(POM Way)**, that is to declare it single time and call multiple times. Its applicable for same class and other class also. You can access it in other class by Public declaration.*

```
public class FormValidation {
  protected static WebDriver driver;

  By errorField = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center_column\"]/div/ol/li");
  By sendButton = By.id("submitMessage");
  By email = By.id("email");


  @BeforeTest()
  public void beforeTest() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
  }

  @Test(priority = 0)
  public void blankFormTest() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=contact");

    WebElement SendButton = driver.findElement(sendButton);
    SendButton.click();
    WebElement ErrorField = driver.findElement(errorField);
    {
      Assert.assertEquals(ErrorField.getText(), "Invalid email address.");

    }
  }

  @Test(priority = 1)
  public void correctEmailonly() {
    WebElement Email = driver.findElement(email);
    Email.sendKeys("kasiatrzaska@o2.pl");
    WebElement SendButton = driver.findElement(sendButton);
    SendButton.click();
    WebElement ErrorField = driver.findElement(errorField);
    {
      Assert.assertEquals(ErrorField.getText(), "The message cannot be blank.");
    }    
  }

}
```